# aura:attribute shared between components

Tags: aura-attribute

I'm new in Salesforce, currently following the trailhead "Input Data Using Forms".

Well I've one main component which include 2 children components:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c"
                    default="{'sobjectType': 'Camping_Item__c', 'Name':'Tent', 'Price__c':233.8, 'Quantity__c':1, 'Packed__c':false, 'Disabled':false}" />
    <!-- aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" -->
    <c:campingHeader />
    <c:campingList items="{!v.items}"/>
    <c:campingListItem items="{!v.items}"/>
</aura:component>
```

The component campingList is to handle the form while campingListItem is to list the collection "items".

When I submit a new item, this one is empty into the list.

**campingList** code:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]"/>
    <c.campingItemForm items="{!v.items}" />
</aura:component>
```

**campingItemForm**:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newItem" type="Camping_Item__c" 
                    required="true"
                    default="{'sobjectType': 'Camping_Item__c', 'Name':'', 'Price__c':0, 'Quantity__c':0, 'Packed__c':false, 'Disabled':false}" />
    
    <!-- CREATE NEW ITEM -->
    <div aria-labelledby="newitemform">
        <!-- BOXED AREA -->
        <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme_default slds-container_small">
        <legend id="newitemform" class="slds-text-heading_small
          slds-p-vertical_medium">
          Add an item
        </legend>
        <!-- CREATE NEW ITEM FORM -->
        <form class="slds-form_stacked">
            <lightning:input aura:id="itemform" label="Item Name"
                             name="itemname"
                             value="{!v.newItem.Name}"
                             required="true"/>
            <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="itemform" label="Quantity"
                             name="itemquantity"
                             min="1"
                             step="1.0"
                             value="{!v.newItem.Quantity__c}"
                             messageWhenRangeUnderflow="You have to purchase at least 1 qty"/>
            <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="itemform" label="Price"
                             name="itemprice"
                             min="0.1"
                             formatter="currency"
                             step="0.1"
                             value="{!v.newItem.Price__c}"
                             messageWhenRangeUnderflow="Enter a price that's at least 1.0€."/>
            <lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="itemform" label="Packed?"
                             name="packed?"
                             checked="{!v.newItem.Packed__c}"/>
            <lightning:button label="Packed"
                              class="slds-m-top_medium"
                              variant="brand"
                              onclick="{!c.clickCreate}"/>
        </form>
        <!-- / CREATE NEW ITEM FORM -->
      </fieldset>
      <!-- / BOXED AREA -->
    </div>
    <!-- / CREATE NEW ITEM -->  
</aura:component>
```

**campingListItem**:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item" >
        <lightning:card title="{!v.item.Name}" iconName="action:goal"
                    class="{!v.item.Packed__c ?
                           'slds-theme_success' : 'slds-text-heading_medium'}">

            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
                Quantity: <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}"/>
            </p>
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
                Price: <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Price__c}" style="currency" />
            </p>
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
                Packed: <ui:outputCheckbox value="{!v.item.Packed__c}"/>
            </p>
        </lightning:card>
    </aura:iteration>    
</aura:component>
```

**ItemFormController**:

```
({
    clickCreate : function(component, event, helper){
        let validItem = component.find('itemform').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
            // Displays error messages for invalid fields
            inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
        }, true);
        
        if(validItem){
            // Create the new item
            let newItem = component.get("v.newItem");
            console.log("Item created: " + JSON.stringify(newItem));
            helper.createItem(component, newItem);
        }
    }
})
```

**ItemForHelper**:

```
({
    createItem: function(component, item) {
        let items = component.get("v.items");
        // Copy the expense to a new object
        // THIS IS A DISGUSTING, TEMPORARY HACK
        let newItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
        items.push(newItem);
        component.set("v.items", items);
    }
})
```

When I set a breakpoint at the end of the helper, I well see the items I've added...but nothing in the list.

Can someone could point me where I'm wrong, thanks a lot.

Cheers

Comment: As a matter of interest, is there a reason you are learning Aura instead of LWC?

Comment: Just following the trailhead training

Comment: Try going through the trailhead instructions and verify you configured everything as written.  I've completed these trails, and they do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from I can't pass back data from a child component to its parent. Seems I need to use event

Comment: Yup, that's the way to use both Aura and LWC:  pass information down from parent-to-child via parameters.  Pass information up from child-to-parent with events.   (And for advanced use cases, you can use [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation) to communicate sibling-to-sibling.). Happy trails!

Comment: Just found in the trailhead training:  Lightning components are supposed to be self-contained. They are stand-alone elements that encapsulate all of their essential functionality. A component is not allowed to reach into another component, even a child component, and alter its internals.

Comment: Correct, and this can be interpreted as: another component can _request_ a change, but it's up to that component to decide if it wants to do anything with the request.   For example, a child can send an event up to its parent, but the parent's event handler chooses whether or not it will take action and what action it chooses to take.